# How to position a view in AbsoluteLayout dynamically (Android)

Tags: android, imageview

How could I set x,y coordination of an ImageView ?

The layout of application is AbsoluteLayout, I tried to call layout() but seems not working (the ImageView stay at 0,0) and setPadding() seems not a feasible solution because I need to do collision detection later.

Sorry, new to Android, thanks in advance.

Comment: `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated and should not be used. "Collision detection" makes it sound like you are developing a game, in which case you probably should not be using widgets like `ImageView`. Instead, draw your 2D game on the `Canvas` -- see the `LunarLander` sample in your SDK.

Comment: You should probably even go further and use the GLSurfaceView